# I'm using Npgsql 7.0.1 in a .Net 6 application. Is it necessary to use prepare() method with the new NpgsqlDataSource.CreateCommand()?

Tags: c#, npgsql

I'm working on an application in .Net 6 using Npgsql 7.0.1.
When I try to run a query and use the .Prepare() method, an error is throwed.

Error:

> System.NotSupportedException : Connection and transaction access is
> not supported on commands created from DbDataSource. Stack Trace: at
> Npgsql.NpgsqlDataSourceCommand.Prepare()

I'm using the NpgsqlDataSource to interact with the database.

For example:

```
await using var cmd = _dataSource.CreateCommand(query);
cmd.Prepare();
```

> ErrorSystem.NotSupportedException : Connection and transaction access
> is not supported on commands created from DbDataSource.

I deleted the Prepare() from the method and it works as expected.

I just want to know if is not necessary anymore, to use prepare command.

Comment: You might want to read this: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/prepare.html. It's never necessary to call Prepare, but sometimes is useful (not in this case as the error tells you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says, Prepare doesn't work with commands you create directly on a data source. This is because the point of Prepare is to keep the command prepared on its connection for multiple invocations, but when the command is created on a data source, there's no stable connection. In other words, the physical connection used could change every time you execute the command.

You can simply get a connection from the data source and create the command over that, at which point you can call Prepare. Another option is simply to use Npgsql's automatic preparation, which means you don't call Prepare at all, but rather let Npgsql decide what/when to prepare based on execution statistics ([see the docs](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/prepare.html) for more info).

Finally, as mentioned above you don't *have* to call Prepare - it's just a perf optimization in case you execute the same SQL multiple times.

Hope that clarifies things.